How to handle clearInterval() from a different function in typescript
I am experiencing a problem on how I will stop the time interval on my code.
How can I clear interval in typescript?
I used interval to generate all the excel tabs separately. Generating excel file is working fine but noticed that the interval still continues to work. Clear interval is not working even if it falls to 'else' statement
public generateFile() {
    this.loadSpinner = true;
    this.dataSource.paginator = null; // remove paginator to generate all rows

    // Current file
    if (this.generateOptionValue == "currentFile") {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.exportFile();
        this.loadSpinner = false;
        this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
      }, 1000)
    } else {
      this.generateEntireFileCounter = () => this.generateEntireFile();
      setInterval(this.generateEntireFileCounter, 2000) //this is my interval
    }
  }

  public generateEntireFile(){
    if(this.fileCounter < this.entireFileCounter){
      this.displayTab(this.fileCounter, this.activeHeaderBtn)
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.exportFile();
        this.fileCounter++;
      },1000)
    } else {
      this.generateOptionValue = "";
      this.loadSpinner = false;
      clearInterval(this.generateEntireFileCounter) //This is where I clear it
      this.displayTab(this.activeHeaderBtn, this.activeHeaderBtn)
    }
  }


setInterval returns you an ID. You need to capture that ID, and use it in your call to clearInterval.

it worked! I missed putting variable that will handle my interval. Thanks @RobbyCornelissen!
